# Render AdaptiveCard in uitableviewcell custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, adaptive-cards

I had been working with Adaptive Card(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/display/libraries/ios). I try to render uiview in a contentView of a uitableviewcell. But it does not present correct form because title label text does not look. But when i scroll the tablelview its appears.
Also some events, as for example a list or actions containers, its event handler not response.
All these problems not happen in a common uiview. I checked that have dynamic constraint but the problem not is it. In the tableview i setted UITableViewAutomaticDimension.